# Modal and event handling with jQuery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm struggling with a problem for several days despite searching all the web out ! Here is my structure, i'm using :

- An HTML form, which has no `submit` button but an `input type='button'` instead. This button launches a bootstrap modal (basically, in a form validation purpose)
- The modal has 2 buttons, 1 submitting the form, 1 cancelling the process.

All I want is **execute a jQuery function when the submitting button is clicked** but... when using :

- `onclick='alert('test')` : it works perfectly fine
- `$('#id').on('click', alert('test'))` : the alert appears **when the page is loaded** and... twice ! (why twice ???)
- `$('#id').click(alert('test'));` : same problem as previous

For several reasons, **i really want to use the 2nd method**. So can anyone help me to understand what's happening here, and how I fix this problem please ?

Here is my form :

```
<form action='' novalidate>
    <input type="button" name="btn" value="send" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_AR_confirmSubmit"/>
</form>
```

And my modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_AR_confirmSubmit" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-dark text-white">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p id='modal_AR_confirmSubmit-body'>Content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id='id'>Valider</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
        </div>
      </div>
       
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#id').on('click', alert('test'))` is not right syntax, event handlers excepts functions:

```
$('#id').on('click', function(){ alert('test')})
```

[jquery on](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer which... works ! (I was convinced I had tried this but... anyway !) I can't help asking myself why you can't mention an existing function right away (instead of re-writing "function(){}")

Comment: @John-Deluxe Np, please consider marking this anwser on ✔︎ button so it marks the question as solved for others. Cheers.

Comment: It's done ! (At least, I think so. if I did wrong, don't hesitate to remind me !)